# C++ Lookup and retrieve a C++ type based on a run-time byte/char

Tags: c++

I receive a large number of different messages. Each message contains a `messageType` byte, which I use to `reinterpret_cast` to a corresponding `struct`.

So there's an implicit, compile-time mapping between the message type and the `struct` representing the message.

Here's a basic implementation:

```
const char* bytes = "";
const MessageType messageType = bytes[0];

switch(messageType)
{
    case MessageType::kMessage1:
    {
        const Message1& msg = reinterpret_cast<const Message1&>(bytes);
        return msg;
    }

    case MessageType::kMessage2:
    {
        const Message2& msg = reinterpret_cast<const Message2&>(bytes);
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

However, there's a lot of messages/case statements to write, each one possibly leading to a mismatching bug.

In an ideal world I'd like to be able to simply retrieve the type from a container (array) using `messageType`:

```
const typeMap.at(messageType)& msg = reinterpret_cast<const typeMap.at(messageType)&>(bytes);
```

What are the available solutions?

Comment: An [x-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)?

Comment: Message parsing systems are certainly not new, and each one I have seen (I have seen my fair share) have a switch like this one. Sometimes they do hide it behind codegen (so that code becomes less error-prone), sometimes they manually write switch statement, sometimes they use already available serialization frameworks, which provide visit-like methods.

Comment: Alternatively, you can store type-erased parsing function in a map, and just pass `bytes` to it. Each individual function will cast the message to proper type and process as required. Please note, switch can be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ templates cannot generate type-based `case`s. Instead you can recursively call a static method in a template class. For example, `reflect::cast`:

```
#include <cinttypes>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

template <char, typename>
struct p;

template <typename ...>
struct reflect;

template <>
struct reflect<> {
    template <typename callback>
    [[noreturn]] static auto cast(char const*, callback const&) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"bad cast"};
    }    
};

template <char index, typename type, typename ... rest>
struct reflect<p<index, type>, rest...> : reflect <rest...> {
    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<type>);
    template <typename callback>
    static auto cast(char const* bytes, callback const& function) {
        if (bytes[0] == index) {
            return function(reinterpret_cast<type const*>(bytes + 1));
        }
        return reflect<rest...>::cast(bytes, function);
    }
};

struct A {
    char value;
};

struct B {
    std::int16_t value;
};

using typeMap = reflect<
    p<0, A>,
    p<1, B>
>;

int main(){
    typeMap::cast(
        "\x01\x2A\x00",
        [](auto undefined){
            std::cout << undefined->value;
        });
}
```

The generated `typeMap::cast` is equivalent to the following code, which is similar to the switch statement from the question:

```
if (bytes[0] == 0) {
    return function(reinterpret_cast<A const*>(bytes + 1));
}
if (bytes[0] == 1) {
    return function(reinterpret_cast<B const*>(bytes + 1));
}
throw std::runtime_error{"bad cast"};
```

Comment: Really like this answer but need some help understanding. Nearly everything is templated, so how does it choose the type based on the fact the message bytes ("\x01\x2A\x00") would only be known at runtime?

Comment: The message bytes are only known at run-time. So IF the first byte is equal to 0, we use `struct A`. If the first byte is 1, we use `struct B` etc

Comment: I've expanded the answer to unroll `cast`

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realise it still evaluates runtime values. That's impressive!!

Comment: Is there a way of doing this by removing 0 and 1 from `typeMap` and instead add a `const` type field to `A` and `B`, with the field hard-coded 0 and 1? I tried this but the trivial check failed when i set the new type field. This means the mapping A and B would come from each struct/self-defining.

Comment: You can remove the `std::is_trivial_v` check, but that steps deeper into undefined behaviour territory. I would recommending packing your structs and reading your compiler's documentation.

Comment: That's fine as I pack the structs when reinterpret-casting at the moment. Is it possible to move the 0 and 1 from `typeMap` in to each struct? I've had a go myself but i've got stuck because I don't have an instance of `type` inside `cast()`, only it's type: https://godbolt.org/z/j37MKv18Y

Comment: Can you make your tags `static constexpr`? https://godbolt.org/z/WrrcanWEz

Comment: That's brilliant. I was wondering how I could make that field part of the type! Thanks

Comment: Got one last final question. Is there a way to change `using typeMap = reflect<A, B>;` to look at an `std::variant`?